# AWS Glue Crawler created a table called `_` in the AWS Glue Data Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue Crawler to scan a Delta table in S3 and add into AWS Glue Data Catalog.

[image]

I am expecting it create a table called `motor`, however, it actually created a table called `_` in the AWS Glue Data Catalog as screenshot shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours, I finally found the issue. It turns out during creating the AWS Glue Crawler, the hidden trailing tab (or spaces) in the delta lake table path caused the issue which makes final table name `_`.

[image]

After I removed trailing tab (or spaces) in delta lake table path by updating from `s3://my-bucket/delta-tables/motor/`    to `s3://my-bucket/delta-tables/motor/` in the crawler config.

The table `motor` got created correctly in the AWS Glue Data Catalog this time:

[image]

The issue is really hard to find. Posting here in case it saves some time for people who meet the same issue in future.